# CSS background-image switcher with cookie: "sets" but don't "gets"!

Tags: jquery, cookies, switch-statement, background-image

My first post, newbie here and to jQuery... I'm reading, studying, trying to get a solid background understanding of jQuery, but I can't help being impatient and jumping in trying to do stuff!

This bit of code has me baffled. It's a sequential toggle background switcher with cookie that I've spent days putting together and trying to make work. What works: it switches between the four backgrounds sequentially, and it appears to set a cookie each time, because the alert confirms it. What doesn't work: the background selection doesn't "stick". When I refresh the page, the background returns to the default as set by the css. I know there's some small but crucial thing wrong, and I've spent many hours trying to figure it out by looking at other examples, here on SO and elsewhere. But no other examples I've found use a toggle sequentially like this. So, looking for a little help, and thanks in advance!

I'm using jquery-1.7.2 and the jquery.cookie plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var bgSwitch = $.cookie("oink");
if (bgSwitch) {
    $("body").css("background-image", bgSwitch);
}
   });
        alert( $.cookie("oink") );
$("#switcher").toggle(
  function () {
    $("body").css({"background-image": "url(images/background/hashbones.gif)"});
                $.cookie("oink", "hashbones!", { expires: 7});
  },
  function () {
    $("body").css({"background-image": "url(images/background/pattern-tile-3.gif)"});
                $.cookie("oink", "tiles!", { expires: 7});
  },
  function () {
    $("body").css({"background-image": "url(images/background/dots.gif)"});
                $.cookie("oink", "DOTS!!!!", { expires: 7});
  },
  function () {
    $("body").css({"background-image": "url(images/background/lines-diag-8px.gif)"});
                $.cookie("oink", "lines again!", { expires: 7});
  }
);
</script>
<style>
body { background: #fff url(images/background/lines-diag-8px.gif) repeat; }  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you toggle the switcher you create a cookie set its value with one possible value (hashbones! / tiles! / DOTS!!!! / lines again!). Assume the current value is "tiles!".
When the page is refreshed bgSwitch get the value of the cookie - "tiles!". So actually you do:

```
$("body").css("background-image", "tiles!");
```

Which makes nothing.

Change the possible values of the cookie to the images themselfs. Something like:

```
function changeBg(bgImage) {
    $("body").css({"background-image": bgImage});
    $.cookie("oink", bgImage, { expires: 7});
}

$("#switcher").toggle(
  function () {
    changeBg("url(images/background/hashbones.gif)");
  },
  function () {
    changeBg("url(images/background/pattern-tile-3.gif)");
  },
  function () {
    changeBg("url(images/background/dots.gif)");
  },
  function () {
    changeBg("url(images/background/lines-diag-8px.gif)");
  }
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works great @Naor! Many thanks for such a quick and simple answer. One small problem remains... When I add a "path" or "domain" option to my cookie (so it's available throughout my site) it breaks the cookie: page refresh then goes back to the original bg, instead of the selected bg. Is there a way to fix that? (Or is it even necessary, because all my site pages are in the same directory.)

Comment: @criz p. critter: Do you have to add those options? Doesn't it work without the options?

Comment: No, I don't think I do. It does work on the sample pages I'm testing it on, but I've yet to add it to all the site pages.But I'm curious why doing so seems to break the scriptI need to add the

Comment: No, I don't think I have to add them, @Naor, but I'm curious why doing so seems to break the script. I thought the cookie code was pretty straight ahead, and I've written it exactly, so it's a mystery. Once I get the switcher added to the whole site, I'll tweak things and see what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: @criz p. critter: If my answer helps, mark it with the V. I will appriciate it :)

Comment: remember I'm new here @Naor... Do you mean the checkmark? If so, done!

Comment: @criz p. critter: This is exactly what I ment, you are GR8 :)

Comment: Btw @Naor, I got the path problem fixed.

Comment: @criz p. critter: What was the solution?? Why it didn't work before??

Comment: I don't really know @Naor. I can't duplicate the fail now. Probably just had a typo somewhere. Everything is working well.

Comment: Can someone help explain how to modify the script to sequentially load the next image each time the page is loaded or refreshed? The cookie is currently set to expire after seven days. Is it possible to set the cookie to expire every few seconds so that a new image loads each time a visitor leaves and comes back to the page? Thanks in advance!